# CountDownTimer using coroutine not working as expected

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I wrote a simple CountDownTimer that starts an action after 5 seconds:

```
class CountDown(val action: () -> Unit, private val delayMillis: Long = 5000) {
    private val job = Job()
    private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default + job)

    private fun startCoroutineTimer() = scope.launch {
        delay(delayMillis)
        if (isActive) {
            action()
        }
    }

    fun start() {
        job.cancelChildren()
        startCoroutineTimer()
    }
}
```

When the timer gets started again before the 5 seconds are up, I want to cancel the old timer and start a new one.

But starting the CountDown three times starts the action three times.

Comment: [I can't reproduce](https://pl.kotl.in/ir9JtdAmD) what you're describing. Can you show your code that produces the action starting three times? By the way, the `isActive` check is redundant because `delay()` cooperates with cancellation.

Comment: Arg, I'm using this in Compose and was using multiple instances of CountDown and probably created new ones on recompose them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem in my compose code and not the CountDown itself.